# Php global keyword in different file

Tags: php, global

I am new to php.
I have one file for the connection to database "**db_connection.php**".

```
<?php
  //With constants
  define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
  define("DB_USER","root");
  define("DB_PASS","");
  define("DB_NAME","db_name");    
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  // Test if connection succeeded
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . 
         mysqli_connect_error() . 
         " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
  }
?>
```

I also have another file called "**functions.php**".where i have a function for the query

```
<?php
    function confirm_query($result_set){
        if (!$result_set) {
            die("Database query failed.");
        }
    }

function find_all_subjects(){
    global $connection;
    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM subjects ";
    $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
    $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    // Test if there was a query error
    confirm_query($subject_set);
    return $subject_set;
}
?>
```

The main file where i call the function "main.php"

```
<?php   require_once("db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php   require_once("functions.php"); ?>
<?php $subject_set = find_all_subjects(); ?>
```

There is no problem everything works fine but can you explain how  **global $connection;** inside **"functions.php"** is actually working?

Comment: How globals do work is the basic of coding. Take a look at php docs. BTW:  hands off from globals. Start coding object oriented and get rid of the loose functions....

Comment: You should use OOP instead of using this style

Using **global** to can access variables defined outside the functions as each function has it's scope. check this doc [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1):

When you include or require PHP files in a webpage, even if you split all your code and functions in separate files, it is essentially the same if you included just one file with all the code from the separate files.

So a variable which you declare / create in "db_connection.php" works the same if you created it in the "functions.php" if you include both files in the same page.

This is why you must be careful with variable, function, etc naming if you use separate files.

Answer (score 0):

when you write that line

```
<?php   require_once("db_connection.php"); ?>
```

then that behave like db_connection.php file write in that file.

then other line you write

```
<?php   require_once("functions.php"); ?>
```

then that behave like you write function.php file in main.php file
so that work fine..